# Jquery issue in Firefox and I.e but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi we've implemented infinite scroll capabilities within our website. All works well within Chrome, but Firefox and I.e are not loading the bellow JavaScript code? We do have https, so could that be the issue, if so how do we work around it.
Bellow is our current code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ajax_arry = [];
    var ajax_index = 0;
    var sctp = 100;
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"function=showData&type=homeactivity&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#postStatus1').html(response);
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var height = $('#postStatus1').height();
        var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(ajax_arry.length>0) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            for(var i=0; i<ajax_arry.length; i++) {
                ajax_arry[i].abort();
            }
        }
        var page = $('#postStatus1').find('.nextpage').val();
        var isload = $('#postStatus1').find('.isload').val();
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && isload=='true') {
            $('#loading').show();
            var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "function=showData&type=homeactivity&page="+page,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#postStatus1').find('.nextpage').remove();
                    $('#postStatus1').find('.isload').remove();
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#postStatus1').append(response);
                }
            });
            ajax_arry[ajax_index++] = ajaxreq;
        }
        return false;
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
            alert("bottom!");
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

... try this... use $(window).load  instead of $(document).ready...

Comment: Well.. Did that solve your "loading" problem ?  I;m sure someone else can explain this better than I, but simply put.. different browsers load the DOM differently... document.ready and window.load are NOT the same... document.ready does what it does when the DOM is ready to load... window.load does it's thing after the page is loaded...